# What are these cookies for: __switchTo5x, __unam, __qca?

Tags: tracking, cookie, safari

I tested on my local Mac's (OS X 10.6.8) Apache. Just now, I did a `print_r($_SERVER)` from a PHP script, and it shows these three cookies.

What is that all about? I didn't set them. Is this something Safari sets up?

They are: `__unam=blah; __qca=POblah; __switchTo5x=25`

Comment: There is only one file. All it does is check the request string, and output print_r($SERVER). Nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- __qca is from Quantcast
- __unam and __switchTo5x are from ShareThis

Presumably you have code for these services somewhere in whatever HTML documents you've been working on.

Most services don't reference their cookies by name when disclosing what data they collect, etc. so you'll have to search around a bit for any details.

Comment: Are you saying code somewhere else on the site somehow can create  these cookies, to then be served by any other page?

Comment: @BobbiBennett Cookies can be set site-wide. Cookies are send at every request.